# android email address logcat shows only numbers

Tags: android

in my android app i have into my strings.xml the following value:

```
<string name="Email">mail@domain.com</string>
```

in my main.class i have this log.e:

```
Log.e("-->", ""+R.string.Email);
```

The output is:

> 2131099691

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.string.email` is a string resource `id`. In order to get the value associated with it, you need to call `getResources().getString()` & pass in the resource's `id` as an argument:

```
Log.e("-->", ""+getResources().getString(R.string.Email));
```

Answer (score 2):

R.string.Email is actually a resource id of an string in xml resource.

That's why it is printing it inside log.

If you want to log actual strung value , you have to use:

```
context.getString(R.string.Email);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Log.e("-->", ""+getResources().getString(R.string.Email));
```